# .serialize() not sending textare content or input content to database

Tags: jquery, input, textarea

I am using this code to submit a forms content to my database.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.post("handlers/comment_handler.php", $("#comments_form").serialize());
});
```

I am using a textarea for the comment but when somebody types and hits submit it does not send what they typed in. I have also tried using  `<input type='text'/>` but that also won't what the user typed in the input field. I believe the .serialize is doing something funny.

Any thoughts?

Comment: <textarea name='comment'></textarea>

Answer (score 1):

That code above is submitting the page when the page is ready, not when the person clicks a button.

I would expect to see

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myButton").click( function(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();
        $.post("handlers/comment_handler.php", $("#comments_form").serialize());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you `name` your input elements.

```
<input type="text" value="test" id="comments_form" name="comments_form"/>
```

**[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/YZQ8B/1/)**

Comment: Yeah I did that just forgot to mention it.

Comment: @Chris, could you post the rest of your html or script as it should work assuming the click/submit handler is wired up correctly.  See the fiddle for an example.